# Connect-N in C; recursive counting problems?

Tags: c, recursion, cygwin

I'm trying to write a version of Connect-4 where you can specify the board size, how many tiles you need to connect to win, and I'm having problems with counting the tiles in specific directions.

I know there are 8 directions on the board, and I know in certain places you can only call for certain directions, and as such I wrote the following function to check for counts in directions, recursively.

```
int DirectionCheck(Board *board, int connect, int prow, int pcol, int drow, int dcol, int player, int count){
    int **spaces = board->spaces;
    int rowindex = (board->rows) - 1;
    int colindex = (board->columns) - 1;

    if((drow == -1) & (dcol == 1)){
        if((spaces[pcol][prow] == player) && (prow > 0) && (pcol < colindex)){
            prow = prow - 1;
            pcol = pcol + 1;
            ++count;
            return DirectionCheck(board, connect, prow, pcol, -1, 1, player, count);
        }else{
            return count;
        }
    }else if((drow == 1) & (dcol == -1)){
        if((spaces[pcol][prow] == player) && (pcol>0) && (prow < rowindex)){
            prow = prow + 1;
            pcol = pcol - 1;
            ++count;

            return DirectionCheck(board, connect, prow, pcol, 1, -1, player, count);
        }else{
            return count;
        }
    }else if((drow == 1) & (dcol == 1)){
        if((spaces[pcol][prow] == player) && (prow < rowindex) && (pcol < colindex)){
            prow = prow + 1;
            pcol = pcol + 1;
            ++count;

            return DirectionCheck(board, connect, prow, pcol, 1, 1, player, count);
        }else{
            return count;
        }
    }else if((drow == -1) && (dcol == -1)){
        if((spaces[pcol][prow] == player) && (pcol > 0) && (prow > 0)){
            prow = prow - 1;
            pcol = pcol - 1;
            ++count;

            return DirectionCheck(board, connect, prow, pcol, -1, -1, player, count);
        }else{
            return count;
        }
    }else if((drow == 1) && (dcol == 0)){
        if((spaces[pcol][prow] == player) && (prow < rowindex)){
            prow = prow + 1;
            ++count;

            return DirectionCheck(board, connect, prow, pcol, 1, 0, player, count);
        }else{
            return count;
        }
    }else if((drow == -1) && (dcol == 0)){
        if((spaces[pcol][prow] == player) && (prow > 0)){
            prow = prow - 1;
            ++count;

            return DirectionCheck(board, connect, prow, pcol, -1, 0, player, count);
        }else{
            return count;
        }
    }else if((drow == 0) && (dcol == 1)){
        if((spaces[pcol][prow] == player) && (pcol < colindex))    {
            pcol = pcol + 1;
            ++count;

            return DirectionCheck(board, connect, prow, pcol, 0, 1, player, count);
        }else{
            return count;
        }
    }else if((drow == 0) && (dcol == -1)){
        if((spaces[pcol][prow] == player) && (pcol > 0)){
            pcol = pcol - 1;
            ++count;

            return DirectionCheck(board, connect, prow, pcol, 0, -1, player, count);
        }else{
            return count;
        }
    }else{
        printf("This should never appear!");

        return 0;
    }
}
```

You pass in a board ( a structure I made that contains a height, width, and a matrix), a position in a row, a position in a column, the direction you want to move in the row, the direction you want to move in the column, the current player, and the count (which is 0 in most cases).

When I run this on a board with one piece in it, it returns a 0, but does not print the "this should never appear!" condition I set. It should return a 1. I'm not sure what I'm doing incorrectly. Any help would be great.

Also, I know all of my other functions are working correctly as I've tested them individually.

I'm calling the function as follows:
    int count = 0;
    int count2 = DirectionCheck(board, 4, prow, pcol, -1, 1, player, count);

My goal is to have this check to see if there's a piece up and to the right of the current piece, which is dynamically allocated based on what the player inputs into the function. If there are no pieces to the top and right of the current piece, it should print out a 0. Otherwise, it should increment the count, and then repeat the function.

Comment: It should only print that message if `drow` and `dcol` are illegal values; why would you ever make such a call?

Comment: I put that there for troubleshooting purposes. If all goes according to plan it should never appear. When I'm done troubleshooting the last else if will become the else and the else condition will go away.

Comment: Thne please explain the problem more clearly; it sounded (to me, at least) that you expected that message but weren't seeing it.

Comment: Please show how you are calling this function.  According to the logic, if you pass in a count of 0 and a direction that would go off the edge of the board, it will return 0.  You really should move the check for whether the given square is occupied by the player to the top of the function and increment count if it is.  You would eliminate about 1/3 of your code if you did that.

Comment: That's a good point about the playercheck, thanks.

I'm updating the main post to display how I call it.

The main post has now been updated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I felt like your function was way too complicated.  The thing you were asking about that was wrong was that the check for the current position being occupied needed to be at the top.  But there were various other things wrong with it:

1. What is `connect`?  It is unused.
2. A few places you used `&` instead of `&&` although it happened to work.
3. A lot of repetition of code.
4. Recursion when not needed.

I took the liberty of rewriting your function like this:

```
// Note, this function should never be called with drow == 0 and dcol == 0.
int DirectionCheck(const Board *board, int prow, int pcol,
        int drow, int dcol, int player)
{
    int count = 0;

    while (prow >= 0 && pcol >= 0 &&
            prow < board->rows && pcol < board->columns) {
        if (board->spaces[pcol][prow] == player)
            count++;
        else
            break;
        prow += drow;
        pcol += dcol;
    }
    return count;
}
```

Comment: Yeah, I understand I recursed when not needed. Should have mentioned that it was required. Thank you for your help though. I ultimately managed to get it work with recursion. Your code is much simpler though.